# MySQL SQL: UPDATE while doing a JOIN on non-normalized table?

Tags: mysql, loops, subquery

**PROBLEM:**

I have two tables, animal table and placeholder table. I want to do an UPDATE
on the animal table so that the appropriate blanks get filled in. The animal
table is not properly normalized.

Is it possible to do this with pure MySQL SQL statements and not resorting to
looping inside a program or script?

**EXAMPLE:**

== Here is the "before" ==

```
animal            placeholder
1 | dog           1 | dog   | log 
1 | snog          2 | cat   | mat
1 | _blank_       3 | bird  | word
2 | cat
2 | sat
2 | _blank_
3 | bird
3 | heard
3 | _blank_
```

== Here is the "after" ==

```
animal            placeholder
1 | dog           1 | dog   | log 
1 | snog          2 | cat   | mat
1 | log           3 | bird  | word
2 | cat
2 | sat
2 | mat
3 | bird
3 | heard
3 | word
```

**QUESTION:**

Can you construct a MySQL SQL statement that will use UPDATE to transform
"before" into "after"??

I am assuming it will be necessary to use JOIN since the query needs to know the correct place to put the placeholders.

== Solution ==

UPDATE animal a
SET name = (
  SELECT noun
  FROM placeholder
  WHERE (
    a.id = id
  )
) WHERE a.name is null;

Comment: Asked question when dealing with non-normalized data in unconventional data table structure from a well-known opensource project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe something similar to this :

```
update animal a
set name = ( select col2 from placeholder where a.name is null and a.id = id )
```

Comment: Almost, but this does not work because it replaces dog/snog , cat/sat , and bird/heard with NULL for some reason. In other words, the UPDATE affects all nine rows instead of just the intended three. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: UPDATE animal a
SET name = (
  SELECT noun
  FROM placeholder
  WHERE (
    a.id = id
  )
) WHERE a.name is null;
Working now, just had to modify the WHERE clause. Thanks again.